# Botones en tiempo de ejecución en Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, layout, xamarin.android

Como puedo crear varios botones en tiempo de ejecución en linearLayout en xamarin c# 
hasta el momento este es mi código

```
Button btn = new Button(this);

btn.LayoutParameters = lparams; 
btn.Text = ("Video"+ 1);
btn.Id= (1);
this.LinearBotones.AddView(btn);
```

pero tengo un error de

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

Comment: En que linea te da ese error? Podrias poner más detalles de la excepción? `this.LinearBotones` está inicializado?

Comment: en la ultima linea es el error.                                            
             containerBotones = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.containerBotones);

            for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
            {
                Button btn = new Button(this);
                btn.Text = "Video " + i;
                btn.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Red);
                this.containerBotones.AddView(btn, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            }

Comment: Que esta usando? xamarin forms o xamarin android?

Comment: Por curiosidad hermano, ¿Lograste solucionarlo?